# Does a morphism of presheaves extend to a morphism of the corresponding sheaves of discontinuous sections uniquely?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, presheaves

The textbook George Kempf: *Algebraic Varieties* defines a *presheaf* as a contravariant functor from the category of the topology of a space $X$ with ordering by inclusion to **Set**. For a presheaf $F$, its *sheaf of discontinuous sections* $D(F)$ is defined as follows: for any open set $V$, we have
$$D(F)(V) := \prod \limits _{x \in V} F_x ,$$
where $F_x$ is the stalk of $F$ at the point $x \in X$. Further, for any open subset $U \subseteq V$, the restriction map $D(F)(V) \to D(F)(U)$ is given by
$$\left( \sigma _{(x)} \right)_{x \in V} \mapsto \left( \sigma _{(x)} \right)_{x \in U} .$$
We have an inclusion morphism $i_F : F \to D(F)$ given by
$$\begin{align}
V &\to D(F)(V) \\
\sigma &\mapsto (\sigma _x)_{x \in V} .
\end{align}$$
The textbook then claims (Lemma 4.1.2-(b), p. 40) that any morphism of presheaves $\alpha : F \to G$ extends *uniquely* to a morphism $D(\alpha ) : D(F) \to D(G)$ which is given by
$$\begin{align}
D(F)(V) \to D(G)(V) \\
\left( \sigma _{(x)} \right)_{x \in V} \mapsto \left( \alpha _x (\sigma _{(x)}) \right)_{x \in V},
\end{align}$$
where for a point $x \in X$, $\alpha _x : F_x \to G_x$ is the map on stalks induced by $\alpha$. We thus get a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F @>{\alpha}>> G\\
@V{i_F}VV @V{i_G}VV \\
D(F) @>{D(\alpha )}>> D(G).
\end{CD}$$

I fail to understand why this map is unique. I have the following counter-example. Consider the topological space $X = \lbrace a, b \rbrace$ with the indiscrete topology $\lbrace X, \phi \rbrace$. We define a presheaf $F$ over $X$ as $D(F)(X) := \lbrace f, g \rbrace$. Thus for any $x \in X$, we get that $F_x = \lbrace f_x \equiv f, g_x \equiv g \rbrace$ is a 2-element set. Then $D(F)(X) = \lbrace f, g \rbrace \times \lbrace f, g \rbrace$ is a 4-element set. Let $\unicode{x1D7D9} : F \to F$ be the identity morphism. This extends the identity morphism $D(F) \to D(F)$, but also to a morphism $\beta : D(F) \to D(F)$ given by:
$$\beta (X) : (f_a , f_b ) \mapsto (f_a , f_b ), \ (g_a , g_b ) \mapsto (g_a , g_b ), \ (f_a, g_b) \mapsto (f_a , f_b ), \ (g_a, f_b) \mapsto (f_a , f_b ) .$$
I am wondering if the uniqueness of extension holds for only certain topological properties, such as for $T_1$ spaces, or quasi-compact $T_1$ spaces. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your counterexample is correct*, the statement is just false. More generally, if $X$ is any indiscrete space and $S$ is a set, we can define a presheaf $F$ on $X$ by letting $F(\emptyset)=\{\star\}$ and $F(X)=S$. Then $F_x = S$ for all $x \in X$, and a morphism $D(F) \to D(F)$ extending $F \to F$ is the same as a map of sets $\alpha : S^X \to S^X$ such that $\alpha$ preserves constant functions. Surely, $\alpha$ is not unique.

<del>I would be pretty surprised though if this uniqueness statement is used an_ywhere else in the book. We only need that there is a natural extension. I would not think more about it then.</del>
EDIT: I was wrong about that

I also doubt that there will be many examples where the extension is unique.

If you want to construct the associated sheaf using $D(F)$, just take the subsheaf $F^{s} \subseteq D(F)$ such that $ F^{s}(U)$ consists of those $s \in \prod_{x \in U} F_x$ such that for every $x \in U$ there is an open neighborhood $x \in V \subseteq U$ and an element in $F(V)$ that induces all the $s_y$ for $y \in V$. It is easy to check that $F^s$ is indeed a sheaf and that we have a morphism of presheaves $F \to F^s$ that satisfies the universal property.

*almost: you didn't define the presheaf on the empty open subset.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing it up. Unfortunately, it is used to prove the universal property of sheafification. The sheafification of a presheaf is defined as the minimal sheaf containing the natural image of the presheaf in its sheaf of discontinuous sections. The universal property is that any morphism from a presheaf to a sheaf can be uniquely extended to a morphism from the sheafification of the presheaf. If the textbook's claim mentioned in the original question was correct, then it can be used to prove the universal property (which holds on its own).

Comment: Then it doesn't work that way. For existence yes, but for uniqueness you just use that definition of the associated sheaf. If two extensions are given, consider their equalizer, which is a subsheaf containing the given presheaf and for which you can apply the definition.